# What are the advantages of 6 wires LVDT over 5 wires LVDT?

Tags: sensor

What are the advantages of 6 wires LVDT over 5 wires LVDT?

Both are the same in that they could be measured using ratiometric calculation.
In case of 5 wires LVDT, it is superior in number of wires to 6 wires LVDT. 
On the other hand, is there any advantage of 6 wires over 5 wires?

Thanks.

[image: 5 wires]

[image: 6 wires]

Comment: why is 5 wires superior to 6 wires?

Comment: >why is 5 wires superior to 6 wires?

Comment: >jsotola  From a standpoint the number of wires. If you say that it is same difference, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 5 wire system you save some copper wires on remote sensors.  This matters on aeroplanes more than elsewhere due to weight and not cost.

With 6 wires you can get full accuracy with simpler receiver circuit.  Check the data sheets to see if it matters, a high quality 5 wire system may surpass a cheap 6 wire system.

The current flowing in the common wire should be small but any current flowing in it will result in voltage drops which will shift the differential voltages by a small amount.  You will often find that two wires are joined in your instrument but having the extra conductor to the sensor means the two phase windings do not interfere with each other.

Like 3/4 wire RTD circuits the extra wire can be compensated for with electronics but sometimes the wire is cheaper than the circuitry.

Also some receivers will only work correctly with one arrangement so you have to match sensor and instrument.

Comment: I appreciate you KalleMP-san. You have amazing practical knowledge!